# How to split $\frac{x^3}{(x^2+5)^2}$ into partial fractions?

Tags: calculus

> Split $\frac{x^3}{(x^2+5)^2}$ into partial fractions.

I have tried letting $$\frac{x^3}{(x^2+5)^2}=\frac{ax+b}{x^2+5}+\frac{cx^3+dx^2+ex+f}{(x^2+5)^2},$$ but this yields a system of only four simultaneous equations.

I have also tried looking at $$\frac{x^3}{(x^2+5)^2} = x \cdot \left( \frac{x}{x^2+5} \right) ^2,$$ but sadly in vain.

Comment: The theory promises that
$$\frac{ax+b}{x^2+5}+\frac{cx+d}{(x^2+5)^2}$$ will work.

Comment: Did you try $(\frac{x^3}{(x^2 +5)}) \times \frac{1}{(x^2 +5)}$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen but that is not the most general form...?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2F(x%5E2%2B5)%5E2

Comment: Yes, @JyrkiLahtonen 's comment is the most general form. Even the term with squared denominator is 4th degree, think of it as a "repeated" 2nd-degree, so you only need first degree in the numerator.

Comment: Plato, you can also think of it this way. In $(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)/(x^2+5)^2$ you can do polynomial (long) division of the numerator by $x^2+5$. The result is that you can write that generic numerator in the form $(Ax+B)(x^2+5)+(Cx+D)$. Then you handle the AB-term and the CD-term separately. In the AB-part you just cancel one $(x^2+5)$-factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, by adding and subtracting $5x$ at the numerator, we obtain 
$$\frac{x^3}{(x^2+5)^2}=\frac{x^3+5x-5x}{(x^2+5)^2}=\frac{x(x^2+5)-5x}{(x^2+5)^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+5}-\frac{5x}{(x^2+5)^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

If we format it into the partial fractions 'template':
$$\frac{x^3}{(x^2+5)^2}=\frac{Ax+B}{(x^2+5)}+\frac{Cx+D}{(x^2+5)^2}$$

Multiplying both sides by the denominator, 
$$\frac{x^3\left(x^2+5\right)^2}{\left(x^2+5\right)^2}=\frac{\left(B+Ax\right)\left(x^2+5\right)^2}{x^2+5}+\frac{\left(D+Cx\right)\left(x^2+5\right)^2}{\left(x^2+5\right)^2}$$

Simplifying, we find that:
$$x^3=\left(B+Ax\right)\left(x^2+5\right)+Cx+D$$
so
$$x^3=Ax^3+Bx^2+5Ax+Cx+5B+D$$
$$x^3=Ax^3+Bx^2+x\left(5A+C\right)+\left(5B+D\right)$$
We have the system of equations
$$\begin{bmatrix}5B+D=0\\ 5AC=0\\ B=0\\ A=1\end{bmatrix}$$
Solving this gives $D=0,\:C=-5,\:B=0,\:A=1$. 
Putting this in our original 'template' gives us:
$$\frac{x}{x^2+5}-\frac{5x}{\left(x^2+5\right)^2}$$

Comment: While this solution is somewhat inelegant, I think it is the easiest to understand.